# Some Drupal 7.34 administrator actons are not working well?

Tags: 7, users

I installed Drupal 7.34 and I saw some thing very strange when doing some administrative actions.

As an example when I'm trying to update a module like this image :

[image]

When I click in Continue it just reloads the page and nothing else is happened.

Another problem is with disabling modules. When I'm trying to disable a few modules, I uncheck them and click Save Configurations but when I check modules page they are still checked and are not disabled!

I've seen the same problem in other parts of website too. for example when I translate a string and click Save, the string is not translated.

Comment: Check the error logs

Comment: @J.Reynolds I checked it, There is no error or even a warning.

Comment: I've had this problem before. It was caused by a wayward module. When I uninstalled the module using Drush (after a lot of guesswork and trial and error), everything went back to normal. Maybe your case is similar, maybe it is not.

Comment: I don't use Drush at all!